# Why does the block get transported down? Using TailWind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<div class="w-auto h-30 m-5 overflow-hidden flex justify-center">
    <div>
      <img class="object-fit" src="https://fs.easybanners.com/Templates/795/TemplateIcon/795.png" alt="" style="height: 50vh;">
      <button class="bg-indigo-500 rounded absolute transform -translate-y-32 translate-x- px-12" style="transform:translateX(10px);"> Contact Us </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm currently using TailWindCSS.
I'm trying to make like a banner for my demo pet shop website.
The problem is that the button gets transported down when I added a style attribute in the button about translate. The button is absolute. Could somebody explain why does this happen in tailwind?

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: just use bootstrap ig

Comment: I want to make a button inside the banner like a button so that the customers can make an appointment for pet grooming.

Comment: @WebDevDude the question is about tailwind

Comment: @WebDevDude I could do that, but I'll just stick with tailwind to save more space. I'm also using the JIT mode of tailwind, so that saves me a lot of space. Tailwind is more customizable too.

Comment: @MJDelosSantos  I think this is help for you. 

https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes

Comment: ok  @MJ Delos Santos

Answer (score 0):

This is what I made so far:

```
<div class="w-auto h-30 m-5 overflow-hidden flex justify-center">
 <div class="">
  <img class="object-fit" src="images/banner/PetShopServicesBanner.png" alt="" style="height: 50vh;">
    <div class="float-right transform -translate-y-14 -translate-x-60">
      <button class="hidden md:block  md:w-52 py-2 bg-orange-500 text-gray-900 rounded absolute"> 
        <p> Make a pet groom schedule </p>
      </button>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```